# How to sort paths into two different categories - Is a file/Is a folder

Tags: c#

When I refer to paths I am talking about directories/file paths (eg. - C:\Friends\noonelovesme.sql or C:\Friends)

I have a method that will ask you to choose a file or folder (You can select multiple files/folder). It will then add all of the files/folders you selected into a ListBox.

I want to be able to sort them so I know which are paths to a file and which are paths to a folder and then add them to string[]'s which will then allow me to the next steps of the program.

Basically all paths that have a file name at the end (c:\dog.txt) will be added to a string[] called IsFile & all paths that end with a folder will be added to a string[] called IsFolder.

**I found this piece of code (for finding out if the path is for a file or folder):**

```
FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(@"c:\Temp");

if (attr.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory))
    MessageBox.Show("Its a directory");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Its a file");
```

**But it seems to not accept arrays**

Comment: So call it inside of a loop (see `while`, `for`, `foreach`)

Comment: If it doesn't accept arrays couldn't you just loop over each item checking them individually?

Comment: `var attributeArray = pathArray.Select( p => File.GetAttributes(p) ).ToArray();`

Comment: Did not think of that @Igor . thank tho

Comment: Wouldn't that be better `var markedPaths = paths.Select(p => new { p, HasDir = File.GetAttributes(p).HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory) }).ToList(); var folders = markedPaths.Where(mp => mp.HasDir).Select(mp => mp.p).ToList(); var files = markedPaths.Where(mp => !mp.HasDir).Select(mp => mp.p).ToList();` though this is one case where a `foreach` loop and using `List.Add` could be clearer and more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put everything inside of a foreach loop and just used an array for the dirs for folders/files.